# Using wincertstore with requests (or converting pfx to pem) gets SSLError

Tags: internet-explorer, python-requests, pem, pfx

I'm trying to use `wincertstore` to pass Internet Explorer (IE) certificates to `requests` in order to download a file. My code is:

```
import requests
import wincertstore

certfile = wincertstore.CertFile()
certfile.addstore('CA')
certfile.addstore('ROOT')
certfile.addstore('foocert_node0')
certfile.addstore('foocert_node1')
certfile.addstore('foocert_node2')

url = 'https://portal.foo.com/blahblahblah'
r = requests.get(url, verify=certfile.name)
```

and the error I get is:

```
SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

The client (which I believe refers to the site I am attempting to download the file at `url` from, ie, foo.com) has given me a certificate with 3 nodes, which is already loaded in the IE cert store. Unfortunately, the client uses IE certificates only.

I'm not sure if I need to explicitly add my client certificate nodes to the certfile, but either way, I still get the same error.

Interestingly, if I simply paste the url into an IE window and hit return, I get a windows security / confirm certificate popup, and once I accept, the file downloads. Unfortunately I'm trying to automate this process (using `selenium`) so I want a solution that works with `requests`.

I've also tried converting the client certificate to pem, by first exporting the windows certificate to a pfx, and then using the following code:

```
import OpenSSL.crypto
import os
import requests
import ssl

def convertpfxtopem(certificate_pfx, password_pfx, certificate_pem):
    f_pem = open(certificate_pem, 'wb')
    pfx = open(certificate_pfx, 'rb').read()
    p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, str.encode(password_pfx))
    f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
    f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
    ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()
    if ca is not None:
        for cert in ca:
            f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
    f_pem.close()
    return Trueurlfile = 'test.xlsx'

convertpfxtopem(certificate_pfx, password_pfx, certificate_pem)
r = requests.get(url, verify=certificate_pem)
```

I get the same SSLError if I use this code.

What am I missing? Thanks so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I am looking for is a lot simpler than I realized. Turns out curl already uses the windows certificate store. So from python / windows, this works:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['curl', '-O', '-J', url], cwd='Temp')
```

The -O and -J flags save the file locally with the name in the file header, and the cwd lets you put the output in a directory of your choosing (which needs to exist already).